# Set the title of the UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uinavigationbar, title

Is it possible to set `self.navigationItem.title = @"MyTitle";`after the view has loaded ?

I am using a search bar and in the same view I feed a UITableView using the search results. So I want to set the search bar's text value as the title of the navigation bar, after the search results loaded.

I am using iOS 4.3.

Comment: Why don't you give a try and you will know yes yes yes it will work...

Comment: I don't ask any without trying on it. Yes I tried. but I failed to find a solution. That's why I asked this.

Comment: Then try `self.title = @"MyTitle";`

Comment: Yes I tried both. But it wasn't effected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. I followed [Pedro Valentini's post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1039-change-font-size-navigation-bar.html#post31603).

This is what I did,

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30)];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setText:text];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:label];
[label release];
```

Comment: This solution will ignore the existing navigation bar's design properties since you're setting your own label. Setting `navBar.topItem.title` as @SamirChen stated is more straightforward and will utilize the design already setup.

Answer (score 15):

Just set the title of `UINavigationBar` like this:

```
navBar.topItem.title = @"sample string";
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally the titleView will be an UILabel, so you can fetch it, cast it, and set its text.

For some reason I had problems using this in `viewDidLoad`, adding it to `viewWillAppear` seemed to do the trick.

```
((UILabel *)self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView).text = @"your title here"
```

Comment: some explanation would help this answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can dynamically set the title of the navigationItem during any part of the lifecycle of a UIViewController.  The set operation is handled by a getter method that sends a message to the UINavigationController to upload the navigation bar's view contents to reflect the new title.

Answer (score 0):

That should work if self in "inside" a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: In my app delegate I do follow,                 UINavigationController *rootViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rootViewController];  rootViewController is the one which I going to change the title dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
_navBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
UINavigationItem *navItem = [UINavigationItem alloc];
navItem.title = @"Title";
```

Try This.

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Terms and Conditions";
```